# How does Shivering Isles scale difficulty?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion [had a prominent difficulty-scaling system](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Leveling), but I've heard that [Shivering Isles](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Shivering:Shivering_Isles) may not be "suitable for low-level characters". Does level-scaling work similarly to the the base game?

Comment: Where did you hear that Shivering Isles "may not be suitable for low-level characters"?  The Wiki doesn't mention this at all, and AKAIK, the expansion will have the same scaling in effect, meaning a level 1 character with a Drain Health 100 spell will WTFPWN absolutely every enemy they meet for a tiny drop of magicka.

Comment: Perhaps you heard about item scaling and got it mixed up with enemy scaling? Some people recommend holding off on certain Shivering Isles quests until you're of a certain level, such that the leveled reward (e.g. Dawnfang/Duskfang) you get is better... but that applies to most quests in the game, not just SI quests.

Comment: @pushasha: Yes, that's exactly what happened.

Comment: @Nelson and pushasha: Feel free to post answer, you both have answered the question.

Comment: Well, the entire premise of the question isn't even valid because nobody will ask that question.  It came from a mis-understanding... so I don't think it really warrants an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After double-checking in the TES Construction Kit, I can confirm that the enemy scaling in the Shivering Isles expansion is exactly the same as it is in the base game -- leveled creatures are picked from a leveled list, based on the player's current level and the creature's base level.

**Base game leveled creature list:**

[image: Base Game Leveled List]

**Shivering Isles leveled creature list:**
[image: Shivering Isles leveled creature list]

Then, if the creature itself has a "PC Level Offset" (a level offset based on the player's current level), that gets applied separately:
[image: Player Offset]

As mentioned in the comments, you seem to have misinterpreted what others meant when they said that lower-level characters should hold off on starting Shivering Isles -- this advice is normally given because of the leveled item rewards that one receives in the expansion, not the leveled enemies. If you get the scaled items at a low level, they will quickly become weak/irrelevant as your player levels up; however, if you receive them at a higher level, they will remain relevant and powerful for much longer (if not for the rest of the playthrough). Check out the [leveled stats for Dawnfang/Duskfang](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Shivering:Duskfang#Leveled_Stats) for an example of how this looks.

Therefore, if you are playing unmodded and want to use the Shivering Isles scaled items for more than a few levels, many will suggest that you wait until your character is at a higher level (30+) so you get the best version of the leveled rewards.

Comment: Related Construction Kit screenshots would improve the answer.

Comment: @user598527 I'll add some when I get back from holiday, but they'll basically just show the SI enemies in the same leveled lists as the normal ones. The other thing I checked for was scripts that might have altered leveling (of which there were none), but that's not really something I can provide screenshots of.

Comment: The scaled item problem is rendered irrelevant with the right mods.

Comment: @Nelson Agreed, I certainly use mods that negate this issue.